Average deviation of a set of 10 random integers from −5 to +5
I calculate the average deviation ($AVD$) of a set of $10$ numbers ($v_{1},v_{2},\cdots,v_{10}$) as follows:

calculate the average of the $10$ numbers: $$AVR =\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{10} v_{n}}{10}$$

calculate the average deviation: $$AVD = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{10} |v_{n}-AVR|}{10}$$


If I were to generate $N$ number of these $10$-number sets, where each set is composed of $\bf{random}$ $\bf{integers}$ from $−5$ to $+5$ (i.e. 11 possible values), then sum the $AVD$ of each set together, then divide that sum by $N$, this would give the average $AVD$ of the $N$ sets. It seems that this average $AVD$ should converge to some value as $N$ increases to $\infty$. I wrote a computer program in Visual Basic (see below) to determine that value, and after $2^{20}$ iterations of the loop it showed $AVD$ = $2.55892$.
Dim n As Long
Dim v() As Integer
Dim sum As double
Dim AVR As Double
Dim AVD As Double
Dim total_AVD As Double
Dim loop_count As Double
Dim average_AVD As Double
Dim repcnt As Long
Const MAX_LOOP_COUNT as Long = 2^20
ReDim v(10)
total_AVD = 0
loop_count = 0
Do
    sum = 0
    For n = 1 To 10
        v(n) = -5 + Int(Rnd() * 11)
        sum = sum + v(n)
    Next
    AVR = sum / 10
    sum = 0
    For n = 1 To 10
        sum = sum + Abs(v(n) - AVR)
    Next
    AVD = sum / 10
    total_AVD = total_AVD + AVD
    loop_count = loop_count + 1
    if loop_count = MAX_LOOP_COUNT then exit do
Loop
average_AVD = total_AVD / loop_count
lblINFO.Caption = "AVD = " & average_AVD & " after " & loop_count & " iterations"

Is there an elegant way to calculate this?

Straight forward Monte-Carlo Simulation

NB that $-5(1)5$ is $11$ integers, not $10$.

FYI - "OP" is either "Original Post" or "Original Poster", depending on the referent.

Your simulation is incorrect, which explains why your number differs significantly from the exact answer offered below.  It really helps to use a high-level language for such work because it helps one to avoid subtle computing mistakes.  For instance, in R the short program mean(replicate(1e5, {   y <- sample(seq(-5, 5), 10, replace = TRUE);   mean(abs(y - mean(y))) })) is straightforward to check, takes only a second to execute, and supports my previous opinion.

@whuber: you say my simulation is incorrect. I have given the code in VB. Can you tell me what is wrong with it?

Sorry--I have neither the inclination nor the time to debug it.

The VB Rnd function is a) not a good one and b) has a period of 16,777,216 random numbers before it repeats, so there's no point in having a loop any larger than that.

@jbowman can you point me to documentation that supports your claim that the period is that small?  I thought it would be 2^64 or at least 2^32,

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/A_PRNG_for_VBA contains the full algorithm, as well as the period (2^24).  I've implemented it and compared its results with R's sample function, and concluded it's not the RNG quality that's the problem here.

@jbowman Thank you! I just wrote a VB program to check the period, and sure enough, you were right, the period is 2^24. I will fix my program to use one with a period of 2^64 and see what results I get with that. But you are saying that the RNG is not the problem. So, assuming I did use a good PRNG, can you give me some idea of what is the problem with my program?

I think the answer to your original question is "No," and after that, you have a programming question that is better asked on StackOverflow - why doesn't this code give the same answer as this other code, basically.

Since 2^20 iterations of my code loop seems to be enough to give the answer to 5 decimal places, which is good enough to confirm whether or not my code is conceptually correct, I won't bother changing it to use a better RNG. But I am still trying to figure out why you guys think it's not correct.

Because the number you got is too far away from the number @whuber's code gets and the code in jimb's answer below gets, which are essentially the same.

So, as I understand it, the answer to my question is "No, there is no elegant solution to the problem." I can live with that.

An elegant solution is in the eye of the beholder.  The answer is 331859304792/129687123005.  If your question is about finding a formula for values other than the asked for parameter values (10 and 11), then maybe there's not generally agreed upon elegant solution.  @whuber 's code below is a pretty short (and efficient) piece of accessible R code.  A short recipe is what's possible and maybe not a standard looking formula.

@JimB However you came up with that rather large numerator and denominator, which, if I understand correctly, a computer can produce in a few seconds at the most, is what I would call the elegant solution that I'm looking for, I will study your solution to see if I can figure that out. And yes, I'd be happy to be able to produce those numbers given the parameter values 10 and 11.

My code took just a few minutes to write and requires less than 0.1 seconds to execute.  The thought that JimB put into this solution took much longer than that, I'm sure ;-).

@whuber It certainly took much more time than your solution.  But when I see that the solution must be an exact rational number rather than just an approximate double precision number, I like the challenge.  Better than hanging out in bars in my retirement.

Here is an "exact" solution using R for the expectation of the sample mean deviation where there are 10 samples ($n=10$) taken from a discrete uniform distribution on the integers -5 to 5 ($k=5$).  I say "exact" because the expectation is a rational number (ratio of two integers) for any positive integer values of $n$ and $k$.  The approach is based on @whuber 's R code (given in a comment in my other answer).  (And there likely isn't any practical reason to get the exact value given @whuber 's code but it's at least interesting to me.)
As before using your notation:
$$E(AVD) = E\left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{10} |v_{n}-AVR|}{10}\right)=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{10} E(|v_{n}-AVR|)}{10}=E(|v_1-(v_1+z)/10|)$$
where $z=\sum_{i=2}^{10} v_i$. As the random variables $v_1,v_2,…,v_{10}$ are all independent of each other, $v1$ and $z$ are also independent of each other.
We first generate the distribution of $z$ using the gmp library.  (I've used $P$ and $Q$ rather than $z$ and $x$ to parallel @whuber 's code.)
library(gmp)
k <- 5
n <- 10
P <- as.bigq(rep(1, 2*k + 1), 1)/(2*k + 1)
Q <- P
v.Q <- c(-k:k)
v.P <- c(-k:k)
for (i in 2:(n-1)) {
    temp.P <- as.bigq(rep(0, 2*i*k + 1), 1)
    for (jQ in 1:(2*k+1)) {
    for (jP in 1:(2*(i-1)*k+1)) {
        j <- v.Q[jQ] + v.P[jP] + i*k + 1
        temp.P[j] <- temp.P[j] <-temp.P[j] + Q[jQ]*P[jP]
    }}
    P <- temp.P
    v.P <- c((-i*k):(i*k))
}

The function convolve (as was used in @whuber 's R code) is unfortunately not available for bigq numbers.
Now we use the combinations of $x$ and $z$ along with their associated probabilities to find the expectation.
v.Q <- as.bigq(v.Q)
v.P <- as.bigq(v.P)
m <- as.bigq(0, 1)
for (jQ in 1:length(Q)) {
for (jP in 1:length(P)) {
    m <- m + abs(v.Q[jQ]-(v.Q[jQ]+v.P[jP])/n)*Q[jQ]*P[jP]
}
}
m
# Big Rational ('bigq') :
# [1] 331859304792/129687123005

And this matches the other answer.

Your title and text seems to ask about the expectation of the mean deviation of a sample size of $N=10$ random integers from -5 to 5.  A secondary question (for which I don't supply an answer) seems to ask about the limit as $N$ increases to $\infty$.
Using your notation we have
$$E(AVD) = E\left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{10} |v_{n}-AVR|}{10}\right)=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{10} E(|v_{n}-AVR|)}{10}=E(|v_1-(v_1+z)/10|)$$
where $z=\sum_{i=2}^{10} v_i$.  As the random variables $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{10}$ are all independent of each other, $v_1$ and $z$ are also independent of each other.
Rather then determining the distribution of $z$ by hand I use Mathematica.  There are 91 possible integer values of $z$ ranging from -45 to +45.  The probability function for $z$ is found as follows:
n = 10;
dist = TransformedDistribution[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n - 1}], 
   Table[x[i] \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{-5, 5}], {i, 1, n - 1}]];
pdf = PDF[dist, z]


Now we can construct the expected value:
mean = Sum[(Abs[x1 - (x1 + z)/10])*(1/11) pdf, {x1, -5, 5}, {z, -45, 45}]
(* 331859304792/129687123005 *)

This value is approximately 2.55892.  There is likely some much more compact approach for any particular sample size.

Creative answer, thanks. Yesterday, Pbulls also gave a nice answer, does anyone know why that answer is no longer available?

@BenP I think it might be only temporarily removed because of a comment I made.  The  combinations used needed to be weighted by their frequency of occurrence.  I suspect that PBulls is now modifying his answer to account for that.  (I'll delete this comment after it reappears.)

Hi guys. It's me, the OP (not sure what OP stands for, but I take it to be me from the context of your comments). Thank you for all your attention to my post. I still have to study much of it. But I just got through updating the post to clarify the problem. Please take a look. And, yes, I hope @PBulls comment will come back!

I forgot to mention that my original answer (2.70526) was wrong, mainly because of my lousy keyboard.

Thanks for your explanation @Jimb and for discovering this adjustment needed in Pbulls simulation. Hope he will fix it, as it would be nice to see how this can be done in R.

@JimB I think you misunderstood what I meant by "N" in my post. I have since updated the post and included the VB code that I wrote to give me what I think to be the correct answer, which I gave incorrectly in my original post, and "N" is the number of iterations of the loop in that code.

I see.  What I have provided is the exact mean of the "sample mean deviation" for a sample size of 10 from a discrete uniform distribution on the 11 integers -5 to 5.  I'll modify my answer appropriately.

+1.  Because more readers will be familiar with R than with Wolfram, here is an R implementation of your (current) solution.  k <- 11; n <- 10; P <- rep(1, k) / k; Q <- rev(P); for (i in seq_len(n - 2)) P <- convolve(Q, P, type = "open"); (mean(P %*% outer(seq_len((k-2) * n + 1) - 1, seq_len(k) - 1, \(z, x) abs(x - (z + x) / n))))

@whuber Wow!  That is fast! (not to mention compact).  You should add that as an answer.

It is fast only because of your initial insight ;-).
